# Twosum problem: Why does code A run so much faster than code B?

Tags: python

I just started leetcoding so I began with some of the easy questions when I discovered that 2 pieces of code that I think perform essentially the same process except the way of displaying the results but the runtime is vastly different.

Code A:

```
class Solution:
def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
    lst_len = len(nums)
    for i in range (0, lst_len-1):
        for j in range (i+1, lst_len):
            if nums[i]+nums[j] == target:
                return[i,j]
```

Code B:

```
class Solution:
def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
    lst_len = len(nums)
    result_lst = [0,0]
    for i in range (0, lst_len-1):
        for j in range (i+1, lst_len):
            if nums[i]+nums[j] == target:
                result_lst[0] = i
                result_lst[1] = j
    return result_lst
```

Is it because code A can finish its execution as soon as the result is found while code B still has to go through both for-loops?

Comment: The first loop returns the first time the if condition matches. Return exits the function. The second version continues through the whole loop.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse , say the range for i is 25 and j is also 25 then we are running solution b 625 times. In case of solution A there is probability that  nums[i]+nums[j] == target happens early (between values 1-1 and the other extreme of 25-25 values of i/j) and you exit the process .

Answer (score 0):

You're right, in the first code:

```
if nums[i]+nums[j] == target:
    return[i,j]
```

right after that condition is met, the answer is returned and no more work is done,

but in the second code, the loop continues

You should check and make sure the both return the same answer